# Implementing recursive function using pointers in D

Tags: pointers, recursion, d

I'm currently trying to implement a recursive function that builds a tree from a list of numbers. I currently have this:

```
Node makelist(Integer[] nums) {
  if (nums.length == 1) {
    return Node(nums[0]);
  } else {
    Integer half = nums.length/2;
    return Node(makelist(nums[0..half]), makelist(nums[half..$]));
  }
}
```

This worked fine for me while `Node` was an object. However, I would like to have `Node` be a struct. As a result, I wrote the following code for `Node`:

```
struct Node {
  Node* left, right, parent;
  Integer val;

  this(Integer val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  this(Node* left, Node* right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    val = min(left.val, right.val);
    left.parent = &this;
    right.parent = &this;
  }
}
```

Now, the compiler obviously doesn't like this very much. However, I have no idea how to take the address of whatever `makelist` returns to make the arguments to the constructor into pointers. Basically, I want to either pass `ref Node`s as both `left` and `right` (but the compiler bitches here as well), or pointers (but I can't seem to get those to work either).

I'm new to low-level code, and would appreciate some help with getting this to work. Basically, I want to use the recursive `makelist` described above, and have two constructors for `Node`s. How can I do that and keep `Node` a struct?

Comment: One of the alternatives is to make makelist() return a pointer to Node. Where did you get that `Integer` type? As far as I know, D does not have it.

Comment: It's an alias for size_t. Should have probably mentioned that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly want, but what about this:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

alias Integer = size_t;

alias Node = _Node*;

struct _Node {
    Node left, right, parent;
    Integer val;

    this(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    this(Node left, Node right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        val = min(left.val, right.val);
        left.parent = &this;
        right.parent = &this;
    }
}

Node makelist(Integer[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 1) {
        return new _Node(nums[0]);
    } else {
        Integer half = nums.length/2;
        return new _Node(makelist(nums[0..half]), makelist(nums[half..$]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using **alias this**

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;
import core.stdc.string;

alias Integer = size_t;

struct Node {
    alias me this;
    @property Node* me() {
        Node* n = new Node();
        memcpy(cast(void*)n, cast(void*)&this, this.sizeof);
        return n;
    }

    Node * left, right, parent;
    Integer val;

    this(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    this(Node left, Node right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        val = min(left.val, right.val);
        left.parent = right.parent = &this;
    }
}

Node makelist(Integer[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 1) {
        return Node(nums[0]);
    } else {
        Integer half = nums.length/2;
        return Node(makelist(nums[0..half]), makelist(nums[half..$]));
    }
}
```